# Issues when compiling iOS 5 app with Google Analytics/GANTracker

Tags: iphone, ios5, compiler-errors, google-analytics, xcode4.3

When trying to install Google Analytics and compile my iOS 5 project, i get the below error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GANTracker", referenced from:  
objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o  
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and the code won't compile.
My build target is iOS 5, I'm linking the below libraries:
- libsqlite3.dylib
- libz.dylib
- libGoogleAnalytics.a
- CFNetwork
- and GANTracker.h

and putting:

```
#import "GANTracker.h"
#define kGANAccountId @"UA-XXXXXXX-X"
static const NSInteger kGANDispatchPeriodSec = 10;
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:kGANAccountId
                                       dispatchPeriod:kGANDispatchPeriodSec
                                             delegate:nil];

NSError *error;
if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1
                                                     name:@"iPhone1"
                                                    value:@"iv1"
                                                withError:&error]) {
    // Handle error here
}

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"my_category"
                                     action:@"my_action"
                                      label:@"my_label"
                                      value:-1
                                  withError:&error]) {
    // Handle error here
}

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/app_entry_point"
                                     withError:&error]) {
    // Handle error here
}
```

Any I've followed everything in: http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/analytics_end_to_end.html

Am I missing a library or framework? 
I'm using Xcode version 4.3.1

Comment: Do you have added CFNetwork Framework ?

Comment: Correct answer posted here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863336/error-message-when-linking-google-analytics-to-ios-app/10099445#10099445][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863336/error-message-when-linking-google-analytics-to-ios-app/10099445#10099445

Answer (score 3):

If you're still wondering what caused your issue, most likely your libGoogleAnalytics library is only compiled for one architecture (ARM) and not i386 (for simulator).

So how can one figure out which architectures are part of the binary? For this purpose [otool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/otool.1.html) can be used, e.g. the following command (on terminal):

`otool libGoogleAnalytics.a -f`

Gives me the following output (please note: I created a fat binary of the Google Analytics library myself):

```
Fat headers
fat_magic 0xcafebabe
nfat_arch 3
architecture 0
    cputype 7
    cpusubtype 3
    capabilities 0x0
    offset 68
    size 243208
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture 1
    cputype 12
    cpusubtype 6
    capabilities 0x0
    offset 243276
    size 231504
    align 2^2 (4)
architecture 2
    cputype 12
    cpusubtype 9
    capabilities 0x0
    offset 474780
    size 229552
    align 2^2 (4)
Archive : libGoogleAnalytics.a (architecture i386)
Archive : libGoogleAnalytics.a (architecture armv6)
Archive : libGoogleAnalytics.a (architecture armv7)
```

In the last 3 lines the supported architectures are shown. You can create your own "fat" binaries using the [lipo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html) command-line tool.

Answer (score 0):

If GANTracker missing from your compile sources? Go to your project settings, then the build target of your application, then the build phases and make sure all of your dependencies are present in the appropriate sections.

[image: build phases image]

Comment: GANTracker is a .h file. Can they be added here? All the frameworks and libraries I require are here by the way...

Comment: Yes, in the compile sources section.

Comment: Done that, and now I get this error too:  warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/The Evo-Stik League/Resources/System Configuration/GANTracker.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386

Comment: Hmm. The rule should be the standard C header file rule found under the Build Rules tab. Did you copy it to your project directory when you added it to Xcode? Try removing it and adding it again (which should change the compile sources in the Build Phases again).

Comment: Done the above about 8 times... Still no  luck :(

Comment: Ah, but what about `clean` and `clean build folder` commands from Xcode’s `product` menu item?

Comment: still no luck... ended up using Flurry analytics instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding everything you added and also adding libGoogleAnalytics_NoThumb.a which you didn't mention. I found it here:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the CFNetwork.framework is listed under "Link Binary With Libraries" In your current target's "Build Phases".

That solved my problem.